# Power BI - DAX equivalent of averageif

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

how can I get DAX version of average if for the following datatable?

```
Week    NScheduled  Ave per week
1         1          1
1         1          1
1         1          1
1         1          1
2         6          3.5
2         1          3.5
3         4          2.666666667
3         3          2.666666667
3         1          2.666666667
```

It is simple average for each week?

Comment: Is this for a measure or a calculated column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula for a calculated column:

```
Ave per week = CALCULATE(
                   AVERAGE(Table1[NScheduled]);
                   FILTER(Table1; Table1[Week] = EARLIER(Table1[Week]))
               )
```